# Iterate latex/kintr code

Tags: knitr, sweave

I am new to knitr/Sweave. I need to prepare different versions of an exam with randomly generated questions. One version per student, each with the student's name on it. Below is a simple example with just two students.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo = FALSE>>=
x <- sample(0:9, 2)
@
William Sealy Gosset $\Sexpr{x[1]}+\Sexpr{x[2]}=$\clearpage

<<echo = FALSE>>=
x <- sample(0:9, 2)
@
Carl Friedrich Gauss $\Sexpr{x[1]}+\Sexpr{x[2]}=$\clearpage

\end{document}
```

As I have one hundred students, I would prefer to have kintr loop through a list of students.

Comment: My approach would be to structure your class lists and symbolic question templates in a database, then use any language of your choice to generate the latex code for you.  A simple batch script could then compile all exams at once.

Comment: Indeed, an option would be to use `make` and leave knitr aside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the names in `name.txt` file, each name on a separate line, and then use this Sweave code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{Sweave}

\title{Exam}

\author{Teacher}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\maketitle

\newpage

<<echo = FALSE, results=tex>>=
name=readLines("name.txt")
n=length(name)
x=sample(0:9, n)
y=sample(0:9, n)

for (i in 1:n) {
  cat(name[i],'\\\\')
  cat('$',x[i],'+',y[i],'=$\\newpage\n',sep="")
}
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: The only problem is that with more complex questions, it may get inpractical to typeset.

Comment: Yes, in fact I don't use Sweave for practical purposes, because it is too complicated. There are appropriate ways that you can do this, like generating LaTeX output and then processing it.